# A-Frame cursor listener on sky element not firing

Tags: html, aframe

I am trying to attach a cursor listener to a sky element (equirectangular image as texture mapped to sphere) in A-Frame. The ultimate goal is to get the 2D coordinates of the texture at the point the cursor intersects with the sphere on click. However, I currently can't get the click event to fire at all. Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, World! - A-Frame</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, World! - A-Frame">
    <script src="aframe.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
      AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
        init: function () {
          this.el.addEventListener('click', function () {
            console.log('I was clicked!');
          });
        }
      }); 
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-camera>
        <a-cursor></a-cursor>
      </a-camera>
      <a-sky cursor-listener src="image.jpg"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The soon-to-be-released version of A-Frame has fixes that will expose the cursor UV intersection data in the click event. https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/tree/master/dist . First I recommend grabbing that.

The sky is far away so you need to extend the `maxDistance` of the raycaster.

```
<a-entity raycaster="maxDistance: 6000; objects: a-sky" cursor></a-entity>
```

https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/components/cursor.html#configuring-the-cursor-through-the-raycaster-component

Comment: default raycaster distance is `Infinity`, right? And if not, the default `a-sky` radius is 5000, so that would likely need to be increased here.

Comment: I increased it. But yeah, the problem is most likely resolved via the first half of my answer.