# Register every click in a-scene

Tags: aframe

I would like to develop an app in aframe, where every click would be registered and would lead me to next picture (a-sky). Currently I have a picture to which I bind the link. I used [this](https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/360-image-gallery/) as base example and develop from that.

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="home" crossorigin="anonymous" src="media/home1600.png">
    <img id="back" crossorigin="anonymous" src="media/back1600.png">
    <img id="forward" crossorigin="anonymous" src="media/forward1600.png">
    <!-- other pictures ... -->

    <!-- Image link template to be reused. -->
    <script id="link" type="text/html">
      <a-entity class="link"
        geometry="primitive: plane; width: 0.25; height: 0.25;"
        material="shader: flat; src: ${thumb};"
        event-set__1="_event: mousedown; scale: 1 1 1"
        event-set__2="_event: mouseup; scale: 1.2 1.2 1"            
        set-image="on: click; target: #image-360; src: ${src}; action: ${action}"
        sound="on: click; src: #click-sound"></a-entity>
    </script>
  </a-assets>

  <!-- 360-degree image. -->
  <!-- Dynamically create a-sky in javascript -->
  <a-sky id="image-360" radius="10" src="#pic0" phi-start="275"></a-sky>

  <input type="hidden" id="pic_num" value="0">

  <!-- Image links. -->
  <a-entity id="links" layout="type: line; margin: 0.4" position="0 -1 -2.5">
    <!-- prepare new links for each action -->
    <a-entity id="back" template="src: #link" data-src="" data-thumb="#back" data-action="back"></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="home" template="src: #link" data-src="" data-thumb="#home" data-action="home"></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="forward" template="src: #link" data-src="" data-thumb="#forward" data-action="forward"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

I really don't like those navigation icons, and as I don't know how to make them more attractive I want to remove them. I want to register forward action when you click anywhere (not just on the forward thumb).

I'm wondering if it is possible to register event click on the a-scene component? I was trying this but without any luck.

Comment: You are required to post the relevant, minimal markup that shows the problem here, not a link to your site that will change tomorrow helping no one in the future: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry. Now I added an example of how I have it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to click on the sphere and get the action of clicking on forward, just add the event to Your a-sky entity:

```
set-image="on: click; target: #image-360; action: forward"
```

it should look like this:

```
<a-sky id="image-360" radius="10" src="#pic0" phi-start="275" 
set-image="on: click; target: #image-360; action: forward"
></a-sky>
```

Not sure how much You've changed the set-image component though. Hope it handles the src somehow.
**UPDATE**
i forgot You whitelisted Your raycaster, the entity should look like this:

```
<a-sky id="image-360" class="link" radius="10" src="#pic0" phi-start="275" 
set-image="on: click; target: #image-360; action: forward"
></a-sky>
```

keep in mind, this set-image here is not the same as it is on the thumbnails. They DONT share data. If You want to manage image changing on the thumbnails AND the sphere/sky, You need to listen for the clicks on the sphere, within the set-image component on one thumbnail ( so ONE entity manages the whole swapping system ), or one entity wrapping the thumnails and sky, or just make a component attached to the scene.

Btw i've BUTCHERED Your code, check out the fiddle, with clicks working on the sphere. https://jsfiddle.net/af9qgdw0/ it works on a sphere, i think the raycaster might have a lenght limit, ( though it says its infinite on the docs ), check this out: [A-Frame cursor listener on sky element not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555844/a-frame-cursor-listener-on-sky-element-not-firing)

**UPDATE 2**
OP want's to perform click action only when you are not dragging picture.
 I think the easiest way is to set up a couple of event listeners:
1. Listen to the camera change via 
`addEventListener('componentchanged', function(evt) {
     if (evt.detail.name === 'rotation') {
     }
});` whereas evt.detail.newData is the new rotation and evt.detail.oldData is the old rotation.
2. in Your set-image Listen for mousedown and mouseup events. Store the oldData.y when mouse down, then check if the newData is equal to the stored data. Remember to make a check if newData is undefined. If old data is equal to the new one, swap the image forward

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get it to work. If I change what you proposed and remove entity with links id, it does not work. It seems like it does not trigger click. Code is accessible here https://github.com/mkopar/virtual-tour-dezela-kozolcev/.

Comment: @thecoparyew updated, works for me, if You still have issues let me know

Comment: In the jsfiddle it looks really cool! I have one more question: do you think it is possible to perform click action only when you are not dragging picture?

Comment: Thank you very much! Yet another question (I promise there will be no more). With the change of a-sky element with a-sphere element all the pictures are mirrored. I think that might be because of the material attribute and it's value (a guess), but if I change this value than there is no picture. So my question is if it's possible to mirror the picture? If it's not possible I'll mirror it in photoshop.

Comment: @thecoparyew to mirror (invert) the pictures give them a scale attribute of scale="-1 1 -1"

Comment: It looks that it wasn't the mirroring problem. When using a-sky component the picture looks like this: http://prntscr.com/fjr01l. When using a-sphere component, the picture looks like this: http://prntscr.com/fjr1fp. What do I need in a-sphere to make it look like in a-sky? I tried all combinations of scaling with 1 and -1 and couldn't make it work.

Comment: @thecoparyew managed to make it work one fiddle with the sky, another with the sphere: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wm7zg7dw/ , https://jsfiddle.net/jnpg2yqp/ .I tried to flip the sky, and rotate the sphere, seems to work fine by now.

Comment: I've tested it in my app but I guess there was misunderstanding, because it's not what I've been looking for. After further investigation I think the problem should be in material="side:back". I changed value of material attribute to "side:front" but then I get just white screen without picture.

Comment: @thecoparyew You still have problems with inverted pictures ? if the sphere is causing trouble, You can use the <a-sky> option, it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/wm7zg7dw/1/